# Why am I not getting errors or result when i use dynamodb through lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I'm new to aws lambda, and i cant find why i don't get any response or error when i use dynamoDB in this simple code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.KrakatoaProcessEventHandler = function(event, context) {
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    dynamodb.listTables(function(err, data) {
     console.log(err);
     console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '));
    });

    event.Records.forEach(function(record) {
        // Kinesis data is base64 encoded so decode here
        payload = new Buffer(record.kinesis.data, 'base64').toString('ascii');
        console.log('Decoded payload:', payload);
    });
    context.succeed("Foo");

};
```

The overall response is:

```
START RequestId: 6f7b57f6-f3fc-11e4-9beb-f5a3878e8dc1
2015-05-06T14:30:28.653Z    6f7b57f6-f3fc-11e4-9beb-f5a3878e8dc1    Decoded payload: Hello, this is a test 123.
2015-05-06T14:30:28.711Z    6f7b57f6-f3fc-11e4-9beb-f5a3878e8dc1    result: "Foo"
END RequestId: 6f7b57f6-f3fc-11e4-9beb-f5a3878e8dc1
REPORT RequestId: 6f7b57f6-f3fc-11e4-9beb-f5a3878e8dc1  Duration: 478.16 ms Billed Duration: 500 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 13 MB
```

I've trying with dynamodb.putItem with same behaviour, everything seems to be correct, but i dont get any response or error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems that context.succeed(); do the job. dynamodb.listTables(function(err, data) {
     console.log(err);
     console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '));
     context.succeed(); 
    });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The anonymous function you pass to `dynamodb.listTables()` is a [callback](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks). Think of them like this:

```js
dynamodb.listTables(function(err, data) {
    // Done listing tables, now do stuff!
});

// If you put code here, it's not guaranteed to run *after* listTables()
```

The Lambda function will stop executing as soon as you call `context.succeed()`. So since you call this "outside" of `listTables()`, the Lambda function may stop before you get any results from Dynamo.

As you noted in your comment, the solution is to do something like the following:

```js
dynamodb.listTables(function(err, data) {
    // Done listing tables, now do stuff!

    context.succeed('Foo');
});
```

Because you put the `context.succeed()` inside the callback, this guarantees the function only completes *after* Dynamo has returned a result and you do things with it.

Asynchronous programming is kind of tricky until you get the hang of it, so read up on callbacks and you can avoid this error in the future!